# What does the keyword `super` in Solidity do?

Tags: solidity, function, function-override

I came across the `super` keyword in Solidity in the context of overriding functions. What does it do?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The [`super` keyword](https://github.com/ethereumclassic/classic-guide/blob/master/old-docs-for-reference/main-wiki.rst/Solidity-Features.rst#access-to-super) in Solidity gives access to the immediate parent contract from which the current contract is derived. When having a `contract A` with a `function f()` that derives from `B` which also has a `function f()`, `A` overrides the `f` of `B`. That means that `myInstanceOfA.f()` will call the version of `f` that is implemented inside `A` itself, the original version implemented inside `B` is not visible anymore. The original function `f` from `B` (being `A`'s parent) is thus available inside `A` via `super.f()`. Alternatively, one can explicitly specifying the parent of which one wants to call the overridden function because multiple overriding steps are possible as exemplified in the example below:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.5;

contract C {
  uint u;
  function f() {
    u = 1;
  }
}

contract B is C {
  function f() {
    u = 2;
  }
}

contract A is B {
  function f() {  // will set u to 3
    u = 3;
  }
  function f1() { // will set u to 2
    super.f();
  }
  function f2() { // will set u to 2
    B.f();
  }
  function f3() { // will set u to 1
    C.f();
  }
}
```

Comment: What if it has multiple inheritance?

Comment: @Emobe solidity uses the same linearization algorithm as python (C3).  So `super` would refer to the next highest class in the linearization.  (caution: in python you read the classes from left to right from lowest to highest; ;in solidity you read from right to left to go from lowest to highest).

Comment: Not sure `B.f()` and `C.f()` are allowed anymore in Solidity v0.6.10 and above. Getting a "Cannot call function via contract type name" error.

Comment: **Update**: the issue was that I was trying to override an already-overriden function. Those accessors still work fine.

Comment: @SCBuergel any way to call an internal method of a parent contract in child contract?

Comment: **important caveat**: "gives access to the immediate parent contract from which the current contract is derived" is slightly misleading. It would be more accurate to say "gives access to the parent contract according to the output of the C3 linearization algorithm", which in some cases (e.g. multiple inheritance) may _not_ be the contract listed as the immediate parent on the contract itself. `contract C is D` does not mean that `super` in context of `C` can be guaranteed to be `D`.

Comment: https://solidity-by-example.org/inheritance/ is very helpful here