# Overwriting of constant variables by inheritance: Why are parent variables only overwritten in functions of the child?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, inheritance, constant

Let's assume I have the following two contracts `Hello` and `Goodbye`, and `Goodbye` inherits from `Hello`. Both declare a constant variable `aString`, i.e. the child contract  `Goodbye` overwrites the parent's value:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;


contract Hello {
    // This will be overwritten by child
    string public constant aString = 'Hello World!';

    // Prints Hello World
    function printMe() returns (string){
        return aString;
    }
}


contract Goodbye is Hello{
    // Overwrites `aString` of parent
    string public constant aString = 'Goodbye World!';

    // Why does this print Hello World, too???
    function printMe() returns (string){
        return super.printMe();
    }

    // Prints Goodbye World as expected
    function printMe2() returns (string){
        return aString;
    }
}
```

So if I call `printMe()` of contract `Hello` it returns `'Hello World!'` as expected.

Moreover, if I create the contract `Goodbye` and call its function `printMe2()` it returns `'Goodbye World!'` because `aString` overwrites the parent's definition of `'Hello World!'`. **However**, if call `printMe()` of `Goodbye` which, in turn, calls `super.printMe()` it **returns** `'Hello World!'`?

**Why** does `printMe()` in `Goodbye` **not return** `'Goodbye World!'`? Why is the overwriting of `aString` by `Goodbye` ignored by the `super.printMet()` call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you say it yourself, you're not calling `aString`, but `super.printMe()`.

Have a deeper explanation of `super`[here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12920/what-does-the-keyword-super-in-solidity-do):

> The super keyword in Solidity gives access to the immediate parent contract from which the current contract is derived.

You are explicitly calling the parent contract Hello, in which `aString` is 
`'Hello, world.'`

Look at the difference if in `printMe2()` you put:

> return super.aString;