# What does super refer to when overriding multiple parents?

Tags: solidity, contract-development

When inheriting from multiple contracts with the same method sometimes I am asked (by the IDE and the compiler) to override a function which is declared in both contracts.

This usually happens when the "parents" my contract is inheriting from implement the IERC165 interface.
In this case I have some code which looks like the following lines (this is ERC721):

```
    /**
     * @dev See {IERC165-supportsInterface}.
     */
    function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId) public view virtual override(ERC165, IERC165) returns (bool) {
        return
            interfaceId == type(IERC721).interfaceId ||
            interfaceId == type(IERC721Metadata).interfaceId ||
            super.supportsInterface(interfaceId);
    }
```

In this example this function overrides an implementation contract and an abstract one, but in other cases I had to implement a function which overrides two implementation contracts.

In that situation what does the "super" keyword refer to?
I am confused because it seems like super refer to a father contract, but in this case there are more than one, so I don't know how to determine to which one super refers to.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12920/what-does-the-keyword-super-in-solidity-do) has some good insights regarding this situation:

"Solidity uses the same linearization algorithm as python (C3). So `super` would refer to the next highest class in the linearization. (caution: in python you read the classes from left to right from highest to lowest; in solidity you read from right to left to go from highest to lowest)."

If you need to call both inherited contracts' function, you can explicitly do so instead of using `super`, where your contract inherits from `ContractB` and `ContractA`:

```
ContractB.func();
ContractA.func();
```